# ChartJS, merge legends for multiple charts

Tags: chart.js

I have multiple charts showing different data. however they are all the same object type e.ge [acc1, acc2, acc3]. Therefore I was wondering if it is possible to have one parent legend set on a page somewhere and clicking it will show/hide all the corresponding dataset from all the charts?

Comment: this might be helpful [chart-js multiple charts with single legend to control](https://codepen.io/shivabhusal/pen/XazwVq?editors=1010)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can hide all the legends of the charts except for one and implement a custom onClick function to handle clicks on that legend and hide all the corresponding datasets for each chart.

The current onClick implementation looks like this:

```
    onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
        var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
        var ci = this.chart;
        var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);

        // See controller.isDatasetVisible comment
        meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;

        // We hid a dataset ... rerender the chart
        ci.update();
    }
```

This function needs to be defined in `options.legend.onClick`. To make this work you would need to rewrite the above function to implement a loop, selecting all the charts necessary and select the meta, hide it and update the chart.